# R for simulating random variable with zero correlation with other variables

Tags: r, vector, random

I am trying to generate random data (using R programming) for variables e1,e2,e3 which should have zero correlation with random variable R. Variables e should have zero correlation with each other. The code written for generating variable e with zero correlation with R as follows:

```
R <- rnorm(120,mean=8,sd=16)

n     <- 120        # length of vectors e

rho   <- 0                   # desired correlation = cos(angle)

nrSamples = 3 # since we have three vectors to estimate (e1,e2,e3)

Id   <- diag(n)

theta<- acos(rho)             # corresponding angle

e <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)

x <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)

X <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)

Xctr <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)

Q <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)

P <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)

x2o <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)

Xc2 <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)

Y <- list(mode="vector",length=nrSamples)


for (i in 1:nrSamples) {

    x[[i]]     <- rnorm(n, 0, 2) 

    X[[i]]     <- cbind(R, x[[i]])         # matrix

    Xctr[[i]]  <- scale(X[[i]], center=TRUE, scale=FALSE) # centered columns(mean 0)


    Q[[i]]    <- qr.Q(qr(Xctr[[i]][ , 1, drop=FALSE])) 

    P[[i]]    <- tcrossprod(Q[[i]])   # = Q Q' # projection onto space defined by x1


    x2o[[i]]  <- (Id-P[[i]]) %*% Xctr[[i]][ , 2]   # x2ctr made orthogonal to x1ctr

    Xc2[[i]]  <- cbind(Xctr[[i]][ , 1], x2o[[i]])  # bind to matrix

    Y [[i]]   <- Xc2[[i]] %*% diag(1/sqrt(colSums(Xc2[[i]]^2)))


    e[[i]] <-  Y[[i]][ , 2] + (1 / tan(theta)) * Y[[i]][ , 1] 

}
vector_1 <- e[[1]]

vector_2 <- e[[2]]

vector_3 <- e[[3]]
```

This code successfully provided three vectors of e with zero correlation with R.   I also need to have zero correlation between e vectors but I do not know how. Any help is appreciated